# Javascript/Angular: timeout wrapped in function not workink with boolean value

Tags: javascript, angular, timeout

In the View I have this condition:

```
    <h3 *ngIf="show">{{users.result}}</h3>
```

In the TypeScript logic I have:

```
show=false; <----as a property
```

And the the following function:

```
timeOut(seconds: number, value:boolean) {
   value = true;      
    setTimeout(
      function() {
        value = false;
      }.bind(this),
      seconds
    );
  }
```

But when I call it, like this:

```
console.log(this.timeOut(3000, this.show));
```

the property `this.show´ gets undefined, but the seconds passed as argument work. I'm missing something and I can't figure out what... Can anyone give a help?

Comment: You want to toggle the `show` property after `seconds`?

Comment: `console.log(this.timeOut(3000, this.show));` should return  `undefined` because `this.timeOut` doesn't return anything

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As i see:

- First of all you **console logging** **function** call **without result**.
- When you **pass** the **boolean value** into the function params it's **being copied**, so when you **change** the value inside the function, it **doesn't affect** the outside variable/field.
- This is very specialized use case, so you do not need to extract it to different function.

My suggestion - just put **setTimeout** call with **arrow function** into some component's method like **ngAfterViewInit** or in **event handler method**:

```
ngAfterViewInit() {
   setTimeout(() => this.show = true, 3000)
}
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: like this:  ` ngAfterViewInit(): void{

    this.timeOut(3000, () => this.show = true);
}´ all gets reddish

Comment: It should be `ngAfterViewInit(): void{ setTimeout(() => this.show = true, 3000); }`, you should call native `setTimeout` function, I mixed up parameters order, updated an answer

Comment: now it says: "Argument of type '3000' is not assignable to parameter of type 'TimerHandler'."

Comment: change `3000` and `() => this.show = true` parameters order like in updated answer

Comment: No problem, i'm glad that it helped!